# Eigen Vector with eigen value in different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

given matrix A, for eigen vector of A, V1 (coordinates in base B), with eigen value X in the field - is V1 by base B' is still an eigen vector of A with the SAME eigen value X?

If so, can you show me how come?

Comment: Eigenvectors and eigenvalues are really properties of the underlying endomorphism. It does not matter which base you pick in order to represent that endomorphism as a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indicating with $M$ the matrix for the change of basis we have that $V_1=MW_1$ and then

$$AV_1=XV_1\implies AMW_1=XMW_1\implies M^{-1}AMW_1=XW_1\implies BW_1=XW_1$$

thus the eigenvalue is $X$ but the representation of $V_1$ changes according to the new basis.